# JSONPARSING error in findViewById

Tags: android, json

Here's my code in the main activity  don'tn know why error in findViewById occurs
 .. this is just my first time in JSON paarsing .

```
  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

        public HomeFragment(){}
        View rootView;
        ListView list;
        ActorsAdapter adapt;
        ArrayList<Actors> actorslist;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

            list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listFeeds);
            actorslist = new ArrayList<Actors>();
            return rootView;

            new ActorsAsynTask().execute("http://jcasim.5gbfree.com/Project/login.php");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listFeeds` It's a component I'm pretty sure is a component that lives in your fragment. Since you haven't return the root view yet, the findViewById is not going to find it. you have to wait until it's on screen to ask for it using `findViewById` (in `onStart()` method) or ask it form the root view before you return it.

it would be `list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listFeeds);`

Answer (score 0):

The `View` of the `Fragment` is not set before the `onCreateView()` returns. Therefore the `findViewById()` tries to find the specified `R.id.listFeeds`from a `null` reference.

Try this instead `list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listFeeds);`